# What is the state of the art in nanophotonic biosensing?

Tags: spectroscopy, molecules, applied-physics, photonics

Over a decade ago I've been doing research in nanophotonic biosensing and all the reviews from those times were very impressive. Some plasmonic structures were capable of single-molecule detection and many of the most impressive structures had fairly simple fabrication method, meaning that commercialization wouldn't be difficult in that regard.

And nowdays when I'm browsing academic job offers in nanophotonics, it feels like a deja-vu. I'm obviously out-of-the loop, but articles from 2022 don't seem very different from 2012 in terms of principles, design, fabrication or capability.

And yet, when I go to get my blood checked, I have to wait as long as decade ago, and there's no "on the spot" results as predicted back then (they have to send the blood sample to a bulky, specialized laboratory). So I don't have an impression of progress.

But perhaps I'm not noticing something. Can someone recommend a review or other article that addresses my impressions? Eg:

- Why don't I see any progress in commercial biosensing?
- What is the actual commercial progress in commercial biosensing?
- What is the scientific progress over the last 10 years in that field?